Should I fill in the foundation when removing an exterior doorway?
My old, detached garage has a poorly-built addition. It has three pedestrian doors (in addition to the garage door. One door is sealed shut. Another is never used, and I decided to remove it, because I'm going to build a workbench along the wall where it is.
I've taken out the door, and there's a section of the foundation wall that was cut out to accommodate it. Should I pour concrete to build up the foundation wall in that gap, or is it okay to just put a pressure treated bottom plate directly on the concrete floor? There’s already substantial water damage from the shoddy construction. I will also be having the concrete pad outside the doorway removed.



Pressure treated is OK, but I would opt for the concrete or mortaring some 1/2 high blocks.
